# Ruby number equal?

Tags: ruby

Two number compare, like below:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

a=1000, b=1000, c=1000, d=1000
puts a==b, c==d
```

but print:

```
false
true
```

Why Ruby compare result like this?

Comment: Remember if you're really baffled to check in `irb` or something like it with `p a` and `p b` (equivalent to `puts a.inspect`) to see what's going on. In this case the differences would be obvious.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ruby's shortcut for setting multiple variables on one line is a little different than C-esque languages.

As pointed out in [SimpleLime's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51971810/ruby-number-equal), the syntax you are using actually creates an array of the `a` variable.

As another pointed out in comment, the way your example is written would evaluate to the following:

```
a = [1000, (b = 1000), (c = 1000), (d = 1000)]
```

While `b`, `c`, and `d` set as expected, `a` does not. `a` is set to an array, while `b`, `c`, and `d` are set to `1000`, since `variable = value` is actually a method call that returns the given value.

The Ruby syntax for what you really intended would look like this:

```
a, b, c, d = 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000
```

or what it actually evaluates to:

```
a, b, c, d = [1000, 1000, 1000, 1000]
```

You can also still do the other shortcut syntax that is pretty common if all the values are the same.

```
a = b = c = d = 1000
```

But beware of this syntax if not using "value" types, such as numerics or booleans, as all the objects will share the same reference.

Comment: List and array form are a lot more slippery in Ruby than in other languages that have a clear distinction.

Answer (score 6):

In ruby you don't need the square brackets `[]` to create an array. So your variable creation line isn't doing what you think:

```
a=1000, b=1000, c=1000, d=1000
p a # [1000, 1000, 1000, 1000]
p b # 1000
p c # 1000
p d # 1000
```

So then, `a == b` is comparing the array `[1000, 1000, 1000, 1000] == 1000`, which is obviously false

Comment: This is parsed as `a=[1000, (b = 1000), (c = 1000), (d = 1000)]`. Assignment is an expression in Ruby, so you get the same result as `a=[1000,1000,1000,1000]` but with the side effects of assigning other variables